# Saving Google Cloud signed URL to a database

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a java method that stores images to my Google bucket and persists the image URL to my database.

```
public void saveImage(Image image, String name, MultipartFile imageFile)
        throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    String fileName = imageFile.getOriginalFilename();
    if (fileName != null && !fileName.isEmpty() && fileName.contains(".")) {
        final String extension = fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf('.') + 1);
        String[] allowedExtention = { "jpg", "jpeg", "png", "gif" };
        for (String s : allowedExtention) {
            if (extension.equals(s)) {
                BlobId blobId = BlobId.of(BUCKET_NAME, fileName);
                BlobInfo blobInfo = storage.create(BlobInfo.newBuilder(blobId).build(), imageFile.getInputStream());

                URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, 0, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
                image.setLocation(url);
                image.setName(name);
            }
        }
    }
```

The following is the URL stored in the database and the image is also stored in my google bucket.

`https://storage.googleapis.com/myBucket/apple.jpg?GoogleAccessId=myBucket@myBucket-333404.iam.gserviceaccount.com&Expires=1657003238&Signature=gYMBIUVAgSQx79FIS%2BrvKMPqtlkSX%2Fb1EHZ40...`

The problem is, this link does not display my image on the front end. Instead I get error 400. Is this huge URL what is supposed to be in my database? I have been working on this since when I woke up but I don't seem to find a solution here or anywhere on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I made a mistake by leaving time expiration at 0. The following works.

```
URL url = storage.signUrl(blobInfo, 60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```